# Given two circles arbitrarily positioned and oriented in $\mathbb{R}^3$, how can I find the nearest points on each circle?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, circles, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

Suppose the first circle has centre and normal $\mathbf{c}_0, \mathbf{n}_0 \!\in\!\mathbb{R}^3$ and radius $r_0\!\in\!\mathbb{R}$. Likewise, $\mathbf{c}_1, \mathbf{n}_1,$ and $r_1$ for the second circle. Further,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{n}_i(\theta_i, \phi_i) = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos\theta_i\sin\phi_i\\
  \sin\theta_i\sin\phi_i\\
  \cos\phi_i
 \end{bmatrix}\ \ \text{for}\ \ i\!\in\{0,1\}
\end{align*}
Additionally, thanks to the prompt responses on my last post, I have the following vectors that are orthonormal to $\mathbf{n}_i$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{u}_i(\theta_i, \phi_i) = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \sin\theta_i\\
  -\cos\theta_i\\
  0
 \end{bmatrix}\ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \mathbf{v}_i(\theta_i, \phi_i) = \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos\theta_i\cos\phi_i\\
  \sin\theta_i\cos\phi_i\\
  -\sin\phi_i
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Can anyone advise me on how I can compute the nearest points $\mathbf{x}_i$ on each circle ($\textit{i.e.}$ $|\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_0|$ is the minimum distance between the circles)? Can the points $\mathbf{x}_i$ be expressed analytically as a function of $\mathbf{c}_i, \theta_i, \phi_i$, and $r_i$ alone? Or can this problem only be solved via a numerical minimisation procedure?

Comment: See https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistanceToCircle3.pdf for a complete analysis.

Answer (score 0):

For a single circle first with radius $r$, if $\mathbf{n}$ is your normal vector, you can use this to find vectors $\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2$ that form an orthonormal basis of the plane containing the circle. Then, with $\mathbf{c}$ the center of the circle, you can parametrize the circle by $\mathbf{c} + (r\text{cos }\theta)\mathbf{u}_1 + (r\text{sin }\theta)\mathbf{u}_2$. This yields a function $P : [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

Doing this with both circles, you get functions $P_1$ and $P_2$. Now if $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are any two points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (in particular, one on each circle) you can compute the square of the distance between them:
$$d(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})^2 = \sum (v_i - w_i)^2$$
Using the parametrizations, you can get a function $f:[0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(\theta_1,\theta_2) = d(P_1(\theta_1),P_2(\theta_2))^2$.

$f$ is a function in two variables and if $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a minimum of it, then $P_1(\alpha)$ and $P_2(\beta)$ are a pair of nearest points on your cirles. Can you compute these minima using some calculus, the formula for $d(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})^2$ and the parametrizations $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: Maybe there's a faster, cleverer way - I just don't see it right now!

Comment: There isn’t in the general case. See the paper I linked in my comment to the question.

Comment: @john Hmm, I considered this approach, but this adds a large number of unknowns to be solved in my system. I basically have a closed surface that is discretely approximated by piece-wise linear polygonal facets that cover the surface. Each facet starts off with an initially perturbed angle. So I want to converge the system such that each polygon has a normal that is as near to that of the surface as possible. I've decided to do this by representing each polygon as a circle, and minimising the sum of the square distances between adjacent circles. It's for this that I require nearest points.

Comment: @john Considering that $\theta_i$ and $\phi_i$ already make up $2N$ unknowns for $N$ circles, the additional parameters for the nearest point to each neighbouring circle significantly adds to the number of unknowns. So perhaps, can you (or anyone else that reads this comment) suggest two alternate points to use for the squared-distance calculation, such that I would not have to parametrically solve for them?